# Storing Route Data

Tags: database, algorithm, path-finding

I have a number of timetables for a train network that are of the form -

> Start Location (Time) -> Stop 1 (time1) -> Stop 2 (time2) -> ... End Location

I.e. each route/timetable is composed of a sequence of stops which occur at ascending times.  The routes are repeated multiple times per day.

Eventually I want to build a pathfinding algorithm on top of this data.  Initially this would return paths from a single timetable/route.  But eventually I would like to be able to calculate optimal journeys across more than one route.

My question is therefore, what is the best way of storing this data to make querying routes as simple as possible?  I imagine a query being of the format...

> Start Location: x, End Location: y, At Time: t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing path finding, a lot of path finding algorithms deal with following the shortest path segment to the next node, and querying paths from that node.  So your queries will end up being, all segments from station x at or after time t, but the earliest for a given distinct destination.

If you have route from Washington, DC to Baltimore, your stop 1 and stop 2 might be New Carrolton and Aberdeen.  So you might store:

```
id (auto-increment), from_station_id, to_station_id, departure_time, arrival_time
```

You might store a record for Washington to New Carrolton, a record for New Carrolton to Aberdeen, and a record from Aberdeen to Baltimore.  However, I would only include these stops if (a) they are possible origins and destinations for your trip planning, or (b) there is some significant connecting route (not just getting of the train and taking the next one on the same route).

Your path finding algorithm is going to have a step (in a loop) of starting from the node with the lowest current cost (earliest arrival) list of the next segments, and the node that segment brings you to.

```
select segments.*
from segments inner joint segments compare_seg on segments.to_station_id = compare_seg.station_id
where departure_time > ?
group by segments.id
having segment.arrival_time = min(compare_seg.arrival_time)
```